# Firestore Rules - Invalid variable name: request

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When editing Firestore rules, I have error:
"Invalid variable name: request"

I am a bit confused because the rules works for me as they should.
Is it editor error or mine?

The code:

```
match /users/{userId} {// USER DOCS
    
      function isSignedIn() {return request.auth != null;}
      function isValidUser() {return request.auth.uid == userId;}   
      
      function isPremium(){
        let user=get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
        return user.data.role=="premium"
      }...
```

and editor image:

[image]

Comment: `request.auth` is scoped to that `isSignedIn()` function block so in that scope request is Invalid variable name to make it work you have to declare that function outside of the `match /users/{userId}` match rule like shown in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `request.auth` is scoped to that `isSignedIn()` function block so in that scope request is Invalid variable name to make it work you have to declare that function outside of the `match /users/{userId}` match rule like shown in [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions)

Answer:
Firestore Security rules using functions need to be defined outside the matchers just like provided in this docs about [custom functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions). In your case `request.auth` is scoped to `isSignedIn()` function block so in that scope request is Invalid variable name.

You have to declare functions and use as follows :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    
    function isValidUser(userId) {
        return request.auth.uid == userId;
    }  
    
    function isPremium(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "premium";
    }
    
    match /users/{userId} {
       allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && isValidUser(userId) && isPremium();
    }
  }
}
```

Reference taken from : [**`Access other documents`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents), [**`Custom functions`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#custom_functions)

Comment: I don't think that's true. At least not anymore, i have functions within matchers and they are fine. I think the issue lays in the way the firestore reports the errors. If the function referencing request is unused firestore.rules warns about invalid varaible name, but if it is used within some seucrity rule the warning is no longer there.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski can you provide your security rules just for confirmation so we can come to some conclusion

Answer (score 1):

@Krzysztof Krzeszewski is right. The error is misleading - if you use the function then the error disappears.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).