# Firestore Security Rules Invalid variable name: request

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm having an error when writing a security rule that verifies if the requestor can make an action. By I'm getting:

> Invalid variable name: request.

Here is my code:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {

  // Check if user is authenticated
  function isAuthenticated() {
    return request.auth != null;
  }

  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function isUserCompanyAdmin(companyID) {
      return isAuthenticated() &&
        request.auth.token.role == 'admin' && request.auth.token.companyID == companyID;
    }

    match /companies/{companyId} {
      allow read, write, update, delete, create, get: if isUserCompanyAdmin(companyId);
    }
  }
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This likely depends on where the function is defined. Please edit your question to include a minimal-but-complete ruleset that reproduces the issue. Or see this question, which is likely the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75713544/firestore-rules-invalid-variable-name-request

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen I've added more context to it. Thanks bud

Comment: One more thing, just in case... if I console.log the token from my app, my custom properties are part of the `claims` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, `request` is only available inside `match` clauses. So you can either pass `request` to the function - or move it into a `match` clause.